# How to ensure a weak_ptr is not created from a temporary shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits, c++-concepts, weak-ptr

Let's have class `Foo` and method `void use_weak_ptr(std::weak_ptr<Foo>)`. Is there a way to ensure - preferably at compile time - that the method is not called with temporary?

Allow this:

```
auto shared = std::make_shared<Foo>();
use_weak_ptr(shared);
```

Do not allow this:

```
use_weak_ptr(std::make_shared<Foo>());
```

Edit: [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/MoG73eTfo) with suggestions.

Comment: Why? To use a `weak_ptr`, you have to `lock()` it first, check if resulting `shared_ptr` is not `nullptr` and then you are sure the pointed-to object still exists, so it doesn't matter if `weak_ptr` was created from temporary or not.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yes, that is a runtime check. With the C++ being able to move a lot of checks and stuff in general to compile time, I was wondering if this could be covered as well.

Comment: You should think about your goal: If you do not want the object to get deleted, use a shared_ptr as argument and if you are ok with the user to delete the shared_ptr, why do you care if he is doing so immediately.

Comment: And there is a hack to prevent temporaries from being passed:  Declare your parameter as non-const reference.

Comment: @gerum Then none of the calls will compile. OP wants the first case to compile.

Comment: @digito_evo Why should the first not compile?

Comment: @gerum I have added a godbolt with examples.

Comment: @gerum Because the first call tries to create a prvalue of type weak_ptr by copy constructing it from the lvalue shared_ptr and obviously the non const lvalue reference parameter can not bind to that rvalue.

Comment: @Croolman Why would you ever want a parameter of type `std::weak_ptr`? In most situation, you should pass a `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You "poison" overload resolution on rvalues

```
void use_weak_ptr(const std::shared_ptr<Foo>&&) = delete;
void use_weak_ptr(std::weak_ptr<Foo>);
```

Comment: This prevents `use_weak_ptr(std::move(shared))`, which is not a temporary variable.

Comment: @康桓瑋 It's an xvalue though which means it's an rvalue. So I don't think it matters much.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Well sure, but `std::weak_ptr` can't move from `std::shared_ptr` anyways, so that is at most a minor inconvenience.

Comment: Just wondering, this might be for a seperate question, but if `Foo` is inherited from some other class, lets say `IFoo` and the functions accept that one, the provided solution ends with ambiguous error. Could this be solved?

Comment: @Croolman It is a different question, and no, not with this solution.

Comment: `const std::shared_ptr<Foo>&&` - really?

Comment: @273K If you're expecting a response, you're going to have to formulate a question.