# How to not allow conversion from temporary shared_ptr to weak_ptr for derived types

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++20, weak-ptr

I have asked this question for [concrete types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72920343/how-to-ensure-a-weak-ptr-is-not-created-from-a-temporary-shared-ptr). The provided solution is sufficient for those, but when it comes to inheritance, it fails. Would there be a solution to that as well?

Lets have a inheritance of classes `Foo` and `IFoo` such that `class Foo: public IFoo` and a function `void use_weak_ptr(std::weak_ptr<IFoo>)`.

Is it possible to **ensure** that this compiles:

```
auto shared = std::make_shared<Foo>();
use_weak_ptr(shared);
```

And this does not:

```
use_weak_ptr(std::make_shared<Foo>());
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/z4PY4sbsd)

Comment: What a real problem are trying to solve? What is an issue with a weak_ptr to a destroyed object?

Comment: This is a question that should be asked, although given the amount of -1 noone cares for the reason. This solves an issue in a large codebase which should be solved by refactor which we cannot afford to do now, so a temporary solution is in place. In a right environment, this should not be needed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solutions - overload `use_weak_ptr` for all `std::shared_ptr`.

```
template <typename T>
void use_weak_ptr(std::shared_ptr<T>&&) = delete;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Tj1a134bd

The linked answer is not a good answer. `const std::shared_ptr<IFoo>&&` - const is redundant.